# How are base registers, limit registers and relocation registers used?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

My understanding in address translation process in MMU(memory management unit)

-> logical address : generated by cpu.programmer concern with this address.

-> virtual address : reside in the hard disk , as a pages.

-> physical address : reside in the RAM. It is the actual address.

1: cpu generate the logical address and send it to the MMU.

2: MMU translate the logical address into the virtual address then translate it to the physical address and send the physical address to RAM.

3: when ever the RAM is full , the page which is not used rapidly is returned to the hard disk , to allocate memory to the other pages(processes).

my questions are :
                    1) where the value of Relocation register is added?
                    2) who decide the value of Relocation Register?
                    3) what to do with the Base register and Limit register , how to use   it?
                    4) where the logical address goes off?

If any body can answer it , It would be grateful to me.
It is requested that , let me know it any misunderstanding in this topic.
-thanks

Answer (score 6):

I can tell you how this works on x86.

All programs in non-64-bit modes operate with addresses combined of two items: `segment selector` (for brevity "selector" is often omitted in text and that may be confusing) and `offset`. This `selector:offset` pair is called the `logical address`.

The selector portion isn't always explicitly specified or manipulated with in code since the CPU has "default" associations of segment registers containing selectors with specific instructions or specific instruction encodings. It's also uncommon to manipulate selectors in 32-bit mode, but is very often necessary in 16-bit code.

The `virtual address` is formed from the logical address either "directly" (in `real` or `8086 virtual` mode) or "indirectly" (in `protected` mode).

`"Direct" virtual address` = `selector` * 16 + `offset`.

`"Indirect" virtual address` = SegmentDescriptorTable[`selector`].Base + `offset`.

SegmentDescriptorTable is either the `Global Descriptor Table` (AKA `GDT`) or the Local Descriptor Table (AKA `LDT`). It's set up by the OS and describes the location and size of various segments of memory. `selector` is used to select a segment in the table. The `Base` entry of the table tells the segment's beginning (virtual address). The `Limit` entry tells the segment size (generally; the details are a little more complex).

When a program tries to access memory with an offset resulting access beyond the end of the segment (the CPU compares `offset` and `Limit`), the CPU generates an `exception` and the OS handles it, by usually terminating the program.

Btw, in `real/v86` mode, even though the virtual address is formed directly from `selector:offset`, there's still a 16-bit `Limit` imposed on offsets, which is why you need to use a different selector to access more than 64KB of memory.

The `Base` entry in a segment descriptor can be used to either isolate the segment from the rest of the memory (`Limit` helps here) or to place or move the entire segment to an arbitrary virtual address without having to modify anything (or much) in the program it belongs to (if we're moving a segment, the data has to be moved in the memory, obviously). Basically, it can be used for relocation purposes. In `real/v86` mode for relocation purposes the `selector` is changed.

The `virtual address` can be further translated to the `physical address` if the CPU is running in `protected mode` and has set up `page tables`. If there're no page tables, the physical address is the same as the virtual address. The translation is done in blocks of physical memory and address ranges that are called `pages` (often 4KB).

There's no dedicated relocation register on x86 CPUs. Relocation can be achieved by adjusting:

1. segment selectors in CPU registers or program's code
2. segment base addresses in GDT/LDT
3. offsets in program's code
4. physical addresses in page tables

As for `virtual address : reside in the hard disk , as a pages`, I'm not sure what exactly you want to say with this, but just because there's virtual to physical address translation, it doesn't mean there's also virtual on-disk memory. There are other uses for the translation besides virtual on-disk memory. And the addresses reside in the CPU and wherever your (and OS's) code writes them to, not necessarily on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your description has a number of mistakes, much of which may be the result of imprecise documentation and common usage.

First of all, there really is no such a thing as a **virtual address**. There are physical and logical addresses. Sadly, the term **virtual address** is   frequently (even in hardware documentation) used when **logical address** is what is meant..

The CPU instruction stream always operates on logical addresses (values may refer to physical addresses).

When the CPU needs to access a logical address, the MMU attempts to translate it to a physical addresses. It does that by looking up the address in a page table.

Several things can happen at that point:

1. There may not be a page table entry for the address => Access violation.
2. The page table entry is marked invalid => Access violation.
3. The page table entry indicates that no physical memory is mapped to it => Page fault.
   (I omit mode access checks).
   It is this last step that last step where virtual memory comes into play. At that point the page fault handler of the operating system needs to find where the corresponding page has been stored to disk, load it, update the page table, and restart the instruction.

The operating system manages the available physical memory by paging writeable memory (that has changed) to disk (read only data does not have to be written back) when there is high demand for physical memory.

I have never heard of a "relocation register" before. But doing a GOOGLE search I can see that some academic material uses it as a confusing pedagogical concept (i.e., with no relation to reality).

Some systems define the page table using base and limit registers. The base registers indicate where the page table starts in memory (this can be either a physical or logical addresses) and the limit register indicates the side of the table.

The registers are usually not loaded directly. Their values are usually written to the hardware Process Context Block (PCB). When the process context is loaded, the page table base and limit are loaded automatically.

On some systems there are multiple page tables. If there are system and user page tables, the user page tables can refer to logical addresses in the system space and the system page tables refer to physical addresses.

Comment: 1) Both "virtual" and "logical" addresses are jargon terms that almost always mean the same thing. Both my OS textbooks use both terms for the same thing (addresses generated by a process). 2) Paging is the modern standard for memory management, but a variety of older systems use a relocation register or some variant of that concept. Sometimes this scheme is called "base and bounds" or "base and limit". Paging takes a lot of effort to do, while base and bounds needs just two registers (or just one if you do no bounds checking).

Comment: Virtual and logical addresses are not the same thing these days. Witness the Android. The physical/logical/virtual distinction is a key one in understanding operating system.

Comment: You have not made it clear in your answer or your comment what the difference between a virtual and a logical address might be. Classically there is no distinction made between virtual and logical addresses. There are some specific systems (e.g. segmentation systems) that might need to do extra translation between virtual and physical addresses, but these are the exception and not the norm, and they don't represent some third type of address. This answer says this and has farm more upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851225/difference-between-physical-logical-virtual-memory-address

Comment: Classically, in there era of small memory, there WAS no difference but there is a difference now with computer systems the implement logical address translation but not virtual translation. (See Android).

Comment: You've got to provide a reference or citation beyond "See Android" because you've said two things that sound wrong. Android implements paging, which is almost always considered a virtual memory scheme with virtual addresses. Android ISAs do not use segmented addressing, which is the only system I know of where there's an extra step to transform a segmented address into a linear address before the linear address is transformed into a physical address. If anything, Android implements virtual memory but does not implement segmented to linear address translation.