# Difference between physical/logical/virtual memory address

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, virtual-memory

I am a little confused about the terms physical/logical/virtual addresses in an Operating System(I use Linux- open SUSE)

Here is what I understand:

1. Physical Address- When the processor is in system mode, the address used by the processor is physical address.
2. Logical Address- When the processor is in user mode, the address used is the logical address. these are anyways mapped to some physical address by adding a base register with the offset value.It in a way provides a sort of memory protection.
3. I have come across discussion that virtual and logical addresses/address space are the same. Is it true?

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Paging explains a large part of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work

Answer (score 74, accepted):

*My answer is true for Intel CPUs running on a modern Linux system, and I am speaking about user-level processes, not kernel code.  Still, I think it'll give you some insight enough to think about the other possibilities*

#### Address Types

Regarding question 3:

> I have come across discussion that virtual and logical
> addresses/address space are the same. Is it true?

As far as I know they are the same, at least in modern OS's running on top of Intel processors.

Let me try to define two notions before I explain more:

- **Physical Address**: The address of where something is physically located in the RAM chip.
- **Logical/Virtual Address**: The address that your program uses to reach its things. It's typically converted to a physical address later by a hardware chip (mostly, not even the CPU is aware really of this conversion).

#### Virtual/Logical Address

The virtual address is well, a virtual address, the OS along with a hardware circuit called the MMU (Memory Management Unit) delude your program that it's running alone in the system, it's got the whole address space(having 32-bits system means your program will think it has 4 GBs of RAM; roughly speaking).

Obviously, if you have more than one program running at the time (you always do, GUI, Init process, Shell, clock app, calendar, whatever), this won't work.

What will happen is that the OS will put most of your program memory in the hard disk, the parts it uses the most will be present in the RAM, but hey, that doesn't mean they'll have the address you and your program know.

**Example:** Your process might have a variable named (counter) that's given the virtual address 0xff (imaginably...) and another variable named (oftenNotUsed) that's given the virtual address (0xaa).

If you read the assembly of your compiled code after all linking's happened, you'll be accessing them  using those addresses but well, the (oftenNotUsed) variable won't be really there in RAM at 0xaa, it'll be in the hard disk because the process is not using it.

Moreover, the variable (counter) probably won't be physically at (0xff), it'll be somewhere else in RAM, when your CPU tries to fetch what's in 0xff, the MMU and a part of the OS, will do a mapping and get that variable from where it's really available in the RAM, the CPU won't even notice it wasn't in 0xff.

Now what happens if your program asks for the (oftenNotUsed) variable? The MMU+OS will notice this 'miss' and will fetch it for the CPU from the Harddisk into RAM then hand it over to the CPU as if it were in the address (0xaa); this fetching means some data that was present in RAM will be sent back to the Harddisk.

Now imagine this running for every process in your system.  Every process thinks they have 4GB of RAMs, no one actually have that but everything works because everyone has some parts of their program available physically in the RAM but most of the program resides in the HardDisk.  Don't confuse this part of the program memory being put in HD with the program data you can access through file operations.

#### Summary

**Virtual address**: The address you use in your programs, the address that your CPU use to fetch data, is not real and gets translated via MMU to some physical address; everyone has one and its size depends on your system(Linux running 32-bit has 4GB address space)

**Physical address**: The address you'll never reach if you're running on top of an OS.  It's where your data, regardless of its virtual address, resides in RAM.  This will change if your data is sent back and forth to the hard disk to accommodate more space for other processes.

All of what I have mentioned above, although it's a simplified version of the whole concept, is what's called the memory management part of the the computer system.

#### Consequences of this system

- Processes cannot access each other memory, everyone has their separate virtual addresses and every process gets a different translation to different areas even though sometimes you may look and find that two processes try to access the same virtual address.
- This system works well as a caching system, you typically don't use the whole 4GB you have available, so why waste that? let others share it and let them use it too; when your process needs more, the OS will fetch your data from the HD and replace other process' data, at an expense of course.

Comment: i find it more helpful then the selected answer. thanks for the write up.

Comment: I agree, this is a much better answer. It actually explains physical/logical/virtual address, whereas the accepted answer only answers the 3 very specific questions.

Comment: well explained answer!

Answer (score 11):

> Physical Address- When the processor is in system mode, the address used by the processor is physical address.

Not necessarily true. It depends on the particular CPU. On x86 CPUs, once you've enabled page translation, all code ceases to operate with physical addresses or addresses trivially convertible into physical addresses (except, SMM, AFAIK, but that's not important here).

> Logical Address- When the processor is in user mode, the address used is the logical address. these are anyways mapped to some physical address by adding a base register with the offset value.

Logical addresses do not necessarily apply to the user mode exclusively. On x86 CPUs they exist in the kernel mode as well.

> I have come across discussion that virtual and logical addresses/address space are the same. Is it true?

It depends on the particular CPU. x86 CPUs can be configured in such a way that segments aren't used explicitly. They are used implicitly and their bases are always 0 (except for thread-local-storage segments). What remains when you drop the segment selector from a logical address is a 32-bit (or 64-bit) offset whose value coincides with the 32-bit (or 64-bit) virtual address. In this simplified set-up you may consider the two to be the same or that logical addresses don't exist. It's not true, but for most practical purposes, good enough of an approximation.

Comment: @ Alexey Thanks a lot. What I understand by your answer is that the above terminology are processor dependent. Is there any general definition for all the three above?

Comment: There probably is. And I think that at least physical and virtual addresses are pretty unambiguous. I've never looked at the terminology. I just know how several different CPUs work with addresses and that's enough for me.

Answer (score 7):

**I am referring to below answer base on intel x86 CPU**

Difference Between Logical to Virtual Address

Whenever your program is under execution CPU generates logical address for instructions which contains (16 bit Segment Selector and 32 bit offset ).Basically Virtual(Linear address) is generated using logical address fields.

Segment selector is 16 bit field out of which first 13bit is index (Which is a pointer to the segment descriptor resides in GDT,described below) , 1 bit TI field ( TI = 1, Refer LDT , TI=0 Refer GDT )

Now Segment Selector OR say segment identifier refers to Code Segment OR Data Segment OR Stack Segment etc. Linux contains one GDT/LDT (Global/Local Descriptor Table) Which contains 8 byte descriptor of each segments and holds the base (virtual) address of the segment.

So for for each logical address, virtual address is calculated using below steps.

1) Examines the TI field of the Segment Selector to determine which Descriptor
Table stores the Segment Descriptor. This field indicates that the Descriptor is
either in the GDT (in which case the segmentation unit gets the base linear
address of the GDT from the gdtr register) or in the active LDT (in which case the
segmentation unit gets the base linear address of that LDT from the ldtr register).

2) Computes the address of the Segment Descriptor from the index field of the Segment
Selector. The index field is multiplied by 8 (the size of a Segment Descriptor),
and the result is added to the content of the gdtr or ldtr register.

3) Adds the offset of the logical address to the Base field of the Segment Descriptor,
thus obtaining the linear(Virtual) address.

Now it is the job of Pagging unit to translate physical address from virtual address.

Refer : Understanding the linux Kernel , Chapter 2 Memory Addressing

Answer (score 6):

**User virtual addresses**
These are the regular addresses seen by user-space programs. User addresses are either 32 or 64 bits in length, depending on the underlying hardware architecture, and each process has its own virtual address space.

**Physical addresses**
The addresses used between the processor and the system's memory. Physical addresses are 32- or 64-bit quantities; even 32-bit systems can use 64-bit physical addresses in some situations.

**Bus addresses**
The addresses used between peripheral buses and memory. Often they are the same as the physical addresses used by the processor, but that is not necessarily the case. Bus addresses are highly architecture dependent, of course.

**Kernel logical addresses**
These make up the normal address space of the kernel. These addresses map most or all of main memory, and are often treated as if they were physical addresses. On most architectures, logical addresses and their associated physical addresses differ only by a constant offset. Logical addresses use the hardware's native pointer size, and thus may be unable to address all of physical memory on heavily equipped 32-bit systems. Logical addresses are usually stored in variables of type unsigned long or void *. Memory returned from kmalloc has a logical address.

**Kernel virtual addresses**
These differ from logical addresses in that they do not necessarily have a direct mapping to physical addresses. All logical addresses are kernel virtual addresses; memory allocated by vmalloc also has a virtual address (but no direct physical mapping). The function kmap returns virtual addresses. Virtual addresses are usually stored in pointer variables.

If you have a logical address, the macro __pa() (defined in ) will return its associated physical address. Physical addresses can be mapped back to logical addresses with __va(), but only for low-memory pages.

[Reference](https://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html).

Answer (score 5):

Normally every address issued (for x86 architecture) is a logical address which is translated to a linear address via the segment tables. After the translation into linear address, it is then translated to physical address via page table.
A nice article explaining the same in depth:
http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/memory-translation-and-segmentation/

Answer (score 1):

Physical Address  is the address that is seen by the memory unit, i.e., one loaded into memory address register.
Logical Address is the address that is generated by the CPU.
The user program can never see the real physical address.Memory mapping unit converts the logical address to physical address.
Logical address generated by user process must be mapped to physical memory before they are used.

Answer (score 1):

Logical memory is relative to the respective program i.e (Start point of program + offset)

Virtual memory uses a page table that maps to ram and disk. In this way each process can promise more memory for each individual process.

Answer (score 0):

In the Usermode or UserSpace all the addresses seen by program are Virtual addresses.
When in kernel mode addresses seen by kernel  are still virtual but termed as logical as they are equal to physical + pageoffset .
 Physical addresses are the ones which are seen by RAM .
With Virtual memory every address in program goes through page tables.

Answer (score 0):

when u write a small program eg:

```
int a=10;
int main()
{
 printf("%d",a);
}   


compile: >gcc -c fname.c
>ls 
fname.o //fname.o is generated
>readelf -a fname.o >readelf_obj.txt
```

/*readelf is a command to understand the object files and executabe file which will be in 0s and 1s. output is written in readelf_onj.txt file*/

```
`>vim readelf_obj.txt`
```

/* under "section header" you will see .data .text .rodata sections of your object file. every starting or the base address is started from 0000 and grows to the respective size till it reach the size under the heading "size"----> these are the logical addresses.*/

```
>gcc fname.c
>ls
a.out //your executabe
>readelf -a a.out>readelf_exe.txt
>vim readelf_exe.txt
```

/* here the base address of all the sections are not zero. it will start from particular address and end up to the particular address. The linker will give the continuous adresses to all the sections (observe in the readelf_exe.txt file. observe base address and size of each section. They start continuously) so only the base addresses are different.---> this is called the virtual address space.*/

Physical address-> the memory ll have the physical address. when your executable file is loaded into memory it ll have physical address. Actually the virtual adresses are mapped to physical addresses for the execution.