# Do we still need Virtual Memory?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

Consider we have large amount of physical memory.

1. **Do we still need virtual memory?**
2. **What is the use of paging in that situation?**

Comment: Do you understand what virtual memory is actually used for?

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is an interview question, asked to one of my friend.

Comment: All those half-dozen reasons still pertain, even with infinite memory. And in fact, some become even *more* important in that situation.

Comment: Can you kindly share those importance of Virtual Memory in that situation.

Comment: Did you want me to copy out the Wikipedia article for you?

Comment: No need of it!!
I'll go through it.

Comment: can't be marked as a duplicate due to lack of upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102669/importance-of-virtual-memory-when-memory-is-very-cheap/31103151#31103151

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - copying it will not help - other students will have handed in copies, the OP wants a unique answer to present.

Comment: @Who downvoted this-
Any reason for downvoting this question?

Answer (score 2):

**Do we still need virtual memory?** Most likely yes, because virtual memory has its perks and advantages.

1. It keeps memory isolated from other processes, which means they cannot access each other data or corrupt them. This can give you a lot of peace of mind.
2. When using certain methods, an OS can "trick" a program into using more memory than possible. Memory can be held temporarily on a secondary storage when not in use and then switched back into memory when needed.
3. Memory doesn't needed to be shared, so all programs can be memory position dependent, without having to worry about having other programs being loaded at the same location.

Generally, virtual memory is vital for any OS, regardless of the amount of memory. The only time I'd say you wouldn't need virtual memory is ***if*** the kernel executed managed code. For example, a JVM executing Java bytecode. Be aware that even in this scheme, the JVM would still manage the memory and program would have an abstract knowledge of its location, not the physical location. Either way you put it, the hardware or the software would **still** emulate virtual memory.

**What is the use of paging in that situation?** It allows the OS to have more memory than it has by utilizing secondary storage. Pages of the RAM are being swapped in and out when needed.

I Hope this helps!